# Mostrar y modificar archivos

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    FILE *fd;

    int main()

    {
        int c;

    char direccion[] = "C:\\Users\\ferneicito\\Desktop\\Programa\\hola.txt";

        fd = fopen(direccion, "a+");
        if (fd == NULL)
        {
            printf ("Error al crear archivo");
            return 1;
        }

        while ((c=getchar())!= EOF)
        {
            fputc(c,fd);
        }
        fclose (fd);
        return 0;
    }
```

Hey muchachos, alguien me podría ayudar, es un problema del tema de archivos y lo que necesito es que al compilar agregar texto, y listo cerrarlo, al compilar otra vez que me salga lo que anteriormente escribí y poder seguir escribiendo, lo hago pero solo puedo agregar texto y al cerrar y volver abrir no me sale lo anterior escrito pero en el archivo .txt si me sale, que podría hacer ahí? Gracias

Comment: Entiendo que por compilar te refieres a ejecutar el programa, pero no se a que te refieres cuando dices que ejecutas el programa y no te sale lo que habías puesto anteriormente, en ninguna parte del código lees el contenido del archivo. Donde esperas ver lo que habías puesto antes?

Answer (score -1):

Por lo que pude ver en tu petición, tu buscas que al ejecutar tu programa, agregar texto, cerrar el programa y al volverlo a abrir que te muestre lo que has ingresado.

Pero en tu código no lees el contenido que almacena el archivo, y si no lo haces no podrás hacer una lectura de él.

No conozco mucho el lenguaje C pero entiendo y me manejo muy bien con c++, se que son cosas distintas, pero con un poco de investigación y en base a mis conocimientos, e creado un código, en donde creo que es lo que tu buscas lograr. Y también creo que si no entiendes el lenguaje c++ con un poco de investigación en el área de ficheros o archivos podrás comprenderlo.

De todos modos he tratado de comentar el código de una manera comprensible para que tu lo entiendas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char Texto[100];
   char AgregarMasTexto;
   ofstream Archivo_Escritura;
   Archivo_Escritura.open("hola.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

    if(Archivo_Escritura.is_open())
    {
       cout << "\tEscritura del archivo." << endl << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << "Desea agregar texto a su archivo (S/N): ";
       cin >> AgregarMasTexto;

        while((AgregarMasTexto == 's') || (AgregarMasTexto == 'S'))
        {
           cout << endl << endl << endl << "Ingrese el texto que desee: ";
           cin >> Texto;
           Archivo_Escritura << Texto << endl;
           cout << "Desea agregar mas texto(S/N): ";
           cin >> AgregarMasTexto;
        }
    }

    else
    {
       cout << "El archivo no fue creado correctamente." << endl;
    }

    ifstream Archivo_Lectura;
    Archivo_Lectura.open("hola.txt", ios::in); 

    if(Archivo_Lectura.is_open())
    {
      cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
      cout << "____________________________________________." << endl << endl;
      cout << "\tLectura del archivo." << endl << endl << endl << endl;
      Archivo_Lectura >> Texto;
      cout << "El texto que existe en su archivo es el siguiente: "<<endl<<endl;

      while(!Archivo_Lectura.eof())
      {
          cout << Texto << endl;
          Archivo_Lectura >> Texto;
      }
     cout << "______________________________________________." << endl << endl;
   }

   else
   {
      cout << "El archivo no fue creado correctamente." << endl;
   }

   Archivo_Lectura.close();
   Archivo_Escritura.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Como norma general, salvo en preguntas con la etiqueta [lenguaje-agnóstico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/lenguaje-agn%C3%B3stico/info), las respuestas han de estar pensadas para el lenguaje de programación en el que se formuló la pregunta. De otro modo, podrían no ser comprendidas, ni ser de ayuda. Además, te arriesgas a [que te voten negativamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Un saludo.